# No more than 10 properties are allowed - GitHub actions

Tags: github, curl, github-actions, github-api

Try to invoke github actions using curl and ending up with below Error:
The same json works perfectly fine when passed through the GitHub actions UI.
Any alternative to pass the same through api using `cURL` ?

**Error**

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request.\n\nNo more than 10 properties are allowed; 18 were supplied.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}
```

CURL Command:

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/xxxx/xxxx/actions/workflows/main.yml/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"topic-branch","inputs":{"account_id": "test-account-005", "app_id": "iu", "customer_id": "self", "customer_name": "xx", "billing_id": "xxxxx", "non_prod_environment_name": "Development", "non_prod_env_id": "dev", "PROJECT_KEY": "CUS", "parent_ou_id": "xxxx", "working_directory": "root", "create_1pass_vault": "false", "cloudcraft": "false", "enterprise_support": "false", "category": "internal", "builder": "xxxxxx", "skip_tekton": "true", "owner": "xxxx", "budget_daily": "20"}}'
```

Comment: Not sure if that's in your real command or not, but `"owner": “xxxx”x` uses "pretty" quotes and also doesn't quote the value entirely.

Comment: Actually, lots of "pretty" quotes in the payload as you show it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - Sorry about that - I edited in my mac, I updated my query but yeah that's still an issue

Comment: It depends a bit on how you use the inputs, but one option I can think of is JSON-escaping the payload so you can submit it as a single string, and then converting back to JSON in your workflow.

Comment: Please include your relevant workflow in your question. From your description, it looks like you want to POST that JSON as a single string and that's what happens when a JSON is passed from the GHA UI. For this, you have to properly escape this something like this with `jq` i.e. `echo $JSON | jq '. | @json | @sh'`: https://jqplay.org/s/-_kVxb3hETn.